# Best way to set ViewData variables for a form page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I guess this is a general pattern we all know. We have an action for displaying a form. The form is psoted to another action. Depending on the validation, we redirect or display again the invalid form. What is annoying is when the form page needs a bunch of variables placed in ViewData (some could be complex data). This obliges to duplicate the code in both actions.

How do you solve this duplication? One example could be an action filter to ensure some variables are set, but defining a new filter for each case is a bit overkill... or an InitAction method? Is there a best practice for that?

```
public ActionResult EditSettings()
{
    // Set some various variables for the view
    ViewData["timezoneinfos"] = TimeZoneInfos;
    ViewData["emailtemplates"] = Templates;

    // Fill a SettingsForm object

    return View(form);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult EditSettings(SettingsForm form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // TODO: save model

        return RedirectToRoute(....);
    }

    // Set some various variables for the view (again)
    ViewData["timezoneinfos"] = TimeZoneInfos;
    ViewData["emailtemplates"] = Templates;

    return View(form);
}
```

Comment: Not sure I get the question right. It seems to me that you want to initialize your viewdatadictionary with some initial values? Why not create a strongly typed viewdata that does this in the constructor? Alternatively create a GetViewData() method that does this initializing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something in the past where let your `[HttpGet]` version of the action take in a the viewModel as a parameter

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditSettings(SettingsForm form)
{
    // Set some various variables for the view
    ViewData["timezoneinfos"] = TimeZoneInfos;
    ViewData["emailtemplates"] = Templates;

    if( form.SomeKeyThatWouldBePopulatedOnPostBack == null )
      // Fill a SettingsForm object

    return View(form);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult EditSettings(SettingsForm form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // TODO: save model

        return RedirectToRoute(....);
    }

    return EditSettings(form);
}
```

Comment: Calling back the "HttpGet method" is after all a clean and quick way to restart the form. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in some cases to avoid that repetition is to override `OnActionExecuted`, and populate `ViewData` there.

In case you need to do that only for specific actions, you can look at `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName` to get the executed Action name.

Comment: +1 Yup an action filter is the order of the day here, oh and strongly typed view models rather than happy magic strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid setting ViewData using arbitrary keys. You should have a ViewModel object which contains all the data needed to display the View.

```
public class EditSettingsViewModel {
   public IEnumerable<TimeZoneInfo> TimeZoneInfos {get;set;} 
    //then your form properties etc...
}
```

Set this model as the view model for your view.

Generally speaking, each View should have its own ViewModel.

Comment: Yes this is generally what I do but sometimes I can't avoid it and/or don't want to write a wrapper model object around another one whose code is not accessible. And anyway, TimeZoneInfos would not be posted back to the POST action...

Comment: It isn't always the best fit. `TimeZoneInfos` would just be null - it wouldn't matter as you wouldn't be checking for it or including it in validation.